# (${var//=/ }) Doesn't work within Alpine Linux while works fine within zsh. Is there similar alternative?

Tags: shell, sh, alpine-linux

I am using this snippet to split string into array

```
line=FOO=BAR
arr=(${line//=/ })
```

which can be later used such as (to obtain split values):

```
varname=${arr[0]}
```

Works great in zsh environment but, it doesn't work within Alpine Linux `/bin/sh` (perhaps, `ash`) environment. I am getting:

> ./env.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "done")

Is there equivalent string splitting command which works on Alpine Linux?

Comment: Indeed, POSIX sh doesn't support either arrays *or* `${var/str/replacement}`, so there are multiple features being relied on that aren't guaranteed to be present in any `/bin/sh` implementation. That said, you can install bash on Alpine, and I'd perhaps suggest doing so.

Comment: (Incidentally, I wouldn't tend to recommend the original code on *any* shell; `IFS='=' read -r varname value` will behave more reliably across all of bash, ksh and zsh, particularly if values contain whitespace or glob characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a heredoc:

```
line=FOO=BAR
IFS='=' read -r var value <<EOF
$line
EOF
```

Comment: Very good point. I'm embarrassed that I missed it earlier myself.